# Slidable Package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile

I am currently studying Flutter and I've been tasked to create a To Do List with the Slidable Package implementation (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable/example), as of now, I do not know where to implement or paste the example code of the slidable package in my code since the example on the package link is different from my line of code, if anyone can help me along with the explanation of how it worked would be very appreciated as I am interested in learning Flutter.

Here's my code without the implementation of the Slidable Package.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:todo_list/widgets/custom_list_tile.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Todo List',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Task List'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<String> todoList = [];
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    todoList.add("My first todo list");
    todoList.add("My second todo list");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 235, 235),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(children: [
                TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Add an Item to the List',
                    ),
                    controller: _textController),
                TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Add an Item Description'),
                    controller: _descriptionController),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        todoList.add(_textController.value.text);
                      });
                      _textController.text = "";
                    },
                    child: const Text("Save"))
              ]),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: todoList.length,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  final data = todoList[index];
                  return CustomListTile(
                    number: index + 1,
                    text: data,
                    listDescription: _descriptionController.text,
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void doNothing(BuildContext context) {}
```

I tried pasting the example code in various parts of my code, I've managed to make it work but not on the list itself with my sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


 final List<String> todoList = [];
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    todoList.add("My first todo list");
    todoList.add("My second todo list");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 235, 235),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(children: [
                TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Add an Item to the List',
                    ),
                    controller: _textController),
                TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Add an Item Description'),
                    controller: _descriptionController),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        todoList.add(_textController.value.text);
                      });
                      _textController.text = "";
                    },
                    child: const Text("Save"))
              ]),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: todoList.length,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  final data = todoList[index];
                  return Slidable(
                    child: CustomListTile(
                      number: index + 1,
                      text: data,
                      listDescription: _descriptionController.text,
                    ),
                    endActionPane: ActionPane(
                      extentRatio: 0.3,
                      motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                      children: [
                        SlidableAction(
                          onPressed: (context) => {},
                          icon: Icons.add,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    startActionPane: ActionPane(
                      extentRatio: 0.2,
                      motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                      children: [
                        SlidableAction(
                          onPressed: (context) {},
                          icon: Icons.delete,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void doNothing(BuildContext context) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I now have a working slidable bar, I just need to implement the functions for delete and add which I've edited and made it to edit.